# Bootstrap grid: last div does not go on next line when reducing window size

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

here's the issue:
Using Bootstrap 3.3.7
I have 6 images (3 icons and 3 progress bars) and wish to have the 2 last ones go to the next line when reducing the window size from col-lg to col-md (making my site as responsive as possible.) The issue is that it does not, here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Boostrap CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
        <div class="container langages" id="skills">
            <div class="row iconskills">
                <!-- HTML -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-1 col-md-offset-1 col-md-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-1">
                    <img class="logohtml" src="img/logos/html5.png" alt="logo html5" />
                </div>
                <div id="progressHtml" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-5 col-lg-3"></div>
                <!-- CSS -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-2 col-md-1 col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-1">
                    <img class="logocss" src="img/logos/css32.png" alt="logo css3" />
                </div>
                <div id="progressCss" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-3"></div>
                <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-1 col-lg-1">
                    <img class="logobs" src="img/logos/bootstrap.png" alt="logo bootstrap" />
                </div>
                <div id="progressBs" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-lg-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

I added 2 screenshots showing what is happening:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCivK.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f976.png)

What is strange is that bootstrap has a grid made of 12 columns, when I check in my divs in col-md I have those 12 columns in my first 4 divs (which is what I want since I want the 2 last to go to the next line) but the behavior is not what I'm expecting.

I'm probably missing something obvious but help would be great, thanks !
Don't hesitate if I'm not clear or missing some infos.

Comment: Can you at least provide a working example to test on, also seems like you're forgetting an offset on the first image

Comment: I edited the code so that it should work to test it. 

Also, what do you mean by I'm missing an offset on the first image, could you be more specific? 

Please note that I started working on the responsiveness starting in lg going down to xs, since I've been stuck on md, do not take into account sm and xs as I've not thoroughly looked into it yet, md is the issue right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to achieve below layout. My views are that you should get familiar with bootstrap built in components(classes). I have changed little bit code of yours, you can further edit it and reference your correct path for images.

Bootstrap 3.3 : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/

Some reference css links that I have used in build

1. **Progress bar :** https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp
2. **Grid :** https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp
3. **Image responsive :** https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_images.asp

**HAPPY CODING** : All the best for you resume, do share the link once it is completed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Boostrap CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
<style>

</style>
</head> 

  <body>
    <section>
        <div class="container langages" id="skills">
            <div class="row iconskills">
                <!-- HTML -->
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-1 col-md-8 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-8">
                        <img class="img-responsive logohtml" src="./img01.png" alt="logo html5" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="progressHtml" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-5 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
                            aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
                              70%
                            </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                
                
                <!-- CSS -->
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-1 col-md-8 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-8">
                        <img class="img-responsive logocss" src="./img01.png" alt="logo css3" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="progressCss" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
                            aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
                              70%
                            </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-1 col-md-8 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-8">
                        <img class="img-responsive logobs" src="./img01.png" alt="logo bootstrap" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="progressBs" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
                            aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
                              70%
                            </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
       
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answer!

The simple fact of adding a new div around each languages helped me sort my problem out!

Thanks again!